# Accidentally deleted a table from redis, is there any roll back like operations?

Tags: linux, redis, rollback

Been working on the Redis since a year, have not faced this issue. Suddenly went to delete a particular record in the Table and deleted the whole table. I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Redis Documentation, it doesn't support rollback transactions, the fact that Redis commands can fail during a transaction without it rolling back may be odd to you if you have a relational DB background.

> However there are good opinions for this behavior:
>
> - Redis commands can fail only if called with a wrong syntax (and the problem is not detectable during the command queueing), or against
>     keys holding the wrong data type: this means that in practical terms a
>     failing command is the result of a programming errors, and a kind of
>     error that is very likely to be detected during development, and not
>     in production.
> - Redis is internally simplified and faster because it does not need the ability to roll back.

Refer to the [Documentation](https://redis.io/topics/transactions)

Answer (score 0):

Redis does not have the rollback feature, except under certain conditions you can cheat with restoring from a file. I mean, you can lock Redis's `dump.rdb` file for write and restart the service. Redis's state will be rolled back to the time of last fsync to the file. Wouldn't recommend doing this, though. Default timer to save Redis state is 15 to 1 min depending on number of writes.

I mean seriously, don't do this.